# WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session_key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

[image]

I am getting this error when i try to access the session I am not able to understand why it is not understanding what is session it is in installed apps it knows what is session

```
def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart

def add_cart(request,id):
    prod = Product.objects.get(id = id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))

    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)
        )
    cart.save()

    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.object.get(product = prod,cart = cart)
        cart_item.quantity += cart_item.quantity
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product = prod,
            quantity = 1,
            cart = cart, 
        )
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('/shop/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The `request` object has no `session_key` but `session`.* And `session_key` is inside `session`. Then :

```
def _cart_id(request):
    # Not request.session_key but request.session.session_key
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart
```